# Why is Drupal displying missing core tables for an external DB?

Tags: 7, database

I'm using an external non Drupal DB to import some data from. The importing itself work, but I also get error like the ones below:

```
Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;lager_db.semaphore&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 480420510502a64252605e0.49437518 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of /srv/www/002/drupal/includes/lock.inc).
```

Why is Drupal even looking to base tables in that Database and how do I get rid of these errors?

My DB setup in settings.php:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => '002_db1',
    'username' => '002_u1',
    'password' => 'password',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'prefix' => '',
    'collation' => 'utf8_swedish_ci',
  );

$databases['lager_db']['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'lager_db',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'host' => '192.168.60.130',
    'prefix' => '',
    'collation' => 'utf8_swedish_ci',
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess you called [db_set_active()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) in some code and forgot to switch back to your master drupal database, so "drupal" execution continued after you intended it to with the current database set as your alternate.

The lager_db probably has no semaphore table, but drupal's trying to call it anyways. You should switch back to drupal at the end of your custom code (or as necessary) with `db_set_active();` it passes the `'default'` parameter if none is given.

Comment: Hmm, I don't use that function myself, but I am using feeds_sql which uses it. there might be a problem there.

Thanx for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I've posted an issue about this in the feeds_sql module's issue queue. [link](http://drupal.org/node/1730990)